# gather the json file into long csv file

Tags: r, json, reshape, tidyr, sparklyr

I want to trnasfer a json file into a long csv file. And my json file has different columns with millions of rows. Is it possible finish it using R? By the way, I have access to Sparklyr, will that be help?

The json file looks like this:

> [
>
> {"num":"1","A":"a","B":"b"},
>
> {"num":"2","C":"c"},
>
> {"num":"3","D":"d"},
>
> ]

I want to get a csv file looks like this:

> num,key,value
>
> 1,A,a
>
> 1,B,b
>
> 2,C,c
>
> 3,D,d

I have tried to convert the json file into a wide csv file. However, I found that the columns are too long and there were multiple NA in the datafram making the csv file very huge. Thus I quited trying this method.

I know I can convert a `wide` dataframe into `long` dataframe with `tidyr` easily. But how to convert a json file into `long` dataframe?

Comment: is this valid JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean a json object like this - where you just extracted the array part?

```
{
"array":[
    {"num":"1","A":"a","B":"b"},
    {"num":"2","C":"c"},
    {"num":"3","D":"d"}
 ]
}
```

So a straight forward approach would be:

```
# using rjson
library(rjson)
test <- fromJSON(file = "test.json")

# extract the "array" which is a list here though
subtest = test[[1]]

# workaround to equalize row length
max_test = max(unlist(lapply(subtest, FUN=length)))
filled_subtest = lapply(subtest, function(x){if(length(x)<max_test){y=append(x,rep(NA,max_test-length(x)));return(y)}else{return(x)}})

# create dataframe
output = data.frame(matrix(unlist(filled_subtest),nrow=length(filled_subtest), byrow=T))
colnames(output) =c("num","key","value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the same assumptions Jannes has about your original JSON object, here's a tidyverse approach:

```
x <- '{
  "array":[
    {"num":"1","A":"a","B":"b"},
    {"num":"2","C":"c"},
    {"num":"3","D":"d"}
    ]
}'

library(jsonlite)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

fromJSON(x, simplifyDataFrame = F) %>% 
  map_depth(
    2, 
    ~as_tibble(.x) %>% 
      gather(key, value, -num)
    ) %>% 
  map(bind_rows)
```

> ```
> $`array`
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
>   num   key   value
>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
> 1 1     A     a    
> 2 1     B     b    
> 3 2     C     c    
> 4 3     D     d
> ```

- `map_depth` says to take your list (here a list of length one, with
  the single item named "array") and apply a function to each nested
  element within (that's the `2` part, while 3 would be 3 levels of
  nesting, etc).
- `as_tibble` takes each `name: value` pair and makes it a column of a dataframe.
- `gather` takes all the columns except `num`, and assigns them as key/value paired rows (this is a conversion from "wide" to "long" data).
- Then finally you `map` over each element of your list (again, only one element, named "array") and use `bind_rows` to combine each nested dataframe within.

This might change some depending on the actual structure of your original object.

---

An alternate version:

```
fromJSON(x, simplifyDataFrame = T) %>% 
  map(
    ~gather(.x, key, value, -num) %>% 
      filter(!is.na(value))
    )
```

This does the conversion from nested object to dataframe for you at the `fromJSON` level. This gives you a potentially very wide dataframe, with lots of columns, so this could be faster or slower than the other method, depending on your data. Then after converting from wide to long, you filter out any NAs that were created during reshaping.